# Discrete Mathematics Book Reference Request

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request

I am an undergraduate pure math student at UC Berkeley. I am in a class which is meant to work on problem solving, particularly with regards to Putnam style questions. My only problem thus far has been my own forgetfulness with regards to some discrete math topics, such as graph theory, and discrete probability.

The analytic topics and linear algebra topics have been significantly easier. In the interests of properly learning some of this material, can anyone recommend me a good "encyclopedia" for Discrete Math? I have used Rosen's book for an introductory class, but the depth of coverage was not sufficient for what I need now.

Some topics I would like to properly learn are:

1) Generating Functions

2) Recursion Theory

3) Intermediate Combinatorics

4) Graph Theory

Comment: Try A walk through combinatorics - by Miklos Bona

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looks like a good reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend [Discrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198507178) by Norman L. Biggs.

You can also try checking out [An Invitation to Discrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198570422) by Jiří Matoušek and Jaroslav Nešetřil.